# Getting the direct download link from sourceforge

Tags: curl, redirect, wget, sourceforge

How to get the direct download link for sites that have a 5 second auto download timer?
I mean I need to upload the file as project in sourceforge but need to place the download link in my website with a download button. On clicking download the user now need to visit sourceforge and wait for download to start but I need the download to start from my website itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you are searching for a way now. There is no way you can do that. I tried many solutions but nothing seems to work. I solved my issue by uploading the file in my server itself.